# Using a password dictionary to decrypt leaked passwords

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, passwords

I'm currently learning about how hackers can decrypt files containing dumps of hashed passwords by using password dictionaries which contain a list of common passwords and comparing the hashed value of those with the ones in the password dump file. I'm testing essentially that method of decryption in the following python function using the password dictionary rockyou.txt from kali linux (which I've seen good reviews about):

```
def decrypt_pass(dict_file,pword_file):
    eh_file = open("eh_passwords.txt","w")
    pFile = open(pword_file,"r")
    dFile = open(dict_file,"r")     

    for eachLine in pFile:
        for line in dFile:
            dFileHash = hashlib.md5(line.strip()).hexdigest()
            
            if eachLine.strip() == dFileHash:
                eh_file.write(line + "\n")
```

This function seems to work When I use two test files, one containing about 12 hashed passwords and the other one containing a small list of common passwords. However, when I run the function using the rockyou.txt and a password dump file (like the one from the linkedin or eHarmony hacks), the function doesn't write anything to the output file.

**Is this happening because the rockyou.txt file is too large for this kind of brute force approach or is it that there are not any passwords that are common between the files? If I'm approaching this from the wrong angle, how should I go about doing the decryption more efficiently?**

#### EDIT

**Below are the two sample files that I used to test the code. The correct matches were found when using these files.**

**test dictionary file**

```
monkey
lovely
jessica
654321
michael
ashley
123456
12345
123456789
password
iloveyou
princess
1234567
rockyou
12345678
abc123
```

**test password dump file (using md5 hash)**

```
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b
25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
f25a2fc72690b780b2a14e140ef6a9e0
8afa847f50a716e64932d995c8e7435a
fcea920f7412b5da7be0cf42b8c93759
f806fc5a2a0d5ba2471600758452799c
25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad
e99a18c428cb38d5f260853678922e03
fc63f87c08d505264caba37514cd0cfd
aa47f8215c6f30a0dcdb2a36a9f4168e
```

Comment: `for line in dFile:` would exhaust file iterator. Second and next passwords are checked vs. 0 positions from dict file. Next time provide [MCVE]. Creating dummy file with _positive_ matches would expose problem immediately.

Comment: You expect md5 hashes to match sha-1 hashes?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Instead of that for loop, are you suggesting that I just check for the end of the file? Also, I just updated the post with the test files that I used.

Comment: No, I suggest reading all words from dict (_once_) andcomputing hashes for all of them (_once_, why should you recompute hashes when you know you may reuse them). The thing is - you don't know why you code does not work, but what _working_ means is not precise. Create a reference data, where you **know** what expected output is and then you have a chance to know if your code is correct. Right now you don't know nothing.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I tried precomputing the hashes and checking if each password exists in the hashtable but it doesn't seem to be finding any matches. I've tried using the rockyou.txt and Crackstation( the smaller one with 64 million passwords) dictionaries. Do you happen to know of any others that might work say for the eHarmony passwords?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 is this question resolved?